# Emails can't be sent to my gmail using Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

what i have in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'pi**@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
```

what i have on `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class contactEmail(forms.Form):
    contact_name=forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject=forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_message=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True)
```

what i have on `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Myportfolio.forms import contactEmail
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=contactEmail()
    else:
        form=contactEmail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name=form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['contact_subject']
            email=form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            message=form.cleaned_data['contact_message']
            send_mail(name, subject, email, message, ['pinkymononyane@gmail.com', email])

    return render(request, 'Myportfolio/contact-me.html', {'form': form})
```

What I have on `contact-me.html`

```html
<form method="post" class="breakable contactUsForm "
    data-thanks-msg="Thank you for contacting me, I have received your message and I will come back to you shortly"
    data-date-format="m/d/Y" data-click-action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_email" placeholder="From Email address"
                        class="form-control s123-force-ltr" data-rule-email="true"
                        data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email." required
                        data-msg-required="This field is required.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="contact_name" placeholder="name" class="form-control" required
                data-msg-required="This field is required.">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message" style="min-height: 100px;"
                required data-msg-required="This field is required."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Contact Me</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="websiteID" value="3438192">
    <input type="hidden" name="moduleID" value="56f3eb72d83fa">
    <input type="hidden" name="layout" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptchaToken" value="">
</form>
```

Please assist, i want people to be able to put in their details incase they want to be intouch when they get to my website contact page and then those details to be sent to my email

Comment: what error are you facing

Comment: When i test to see if the send email form works, i find it doesnt and i get no error. The page just freezes

Answer (score 1):

Please set the Gmail configuration to allow less secure app in Gmail security setting.

Answer (score 0):

is this website live? I know that AWS free tier doesn't allow smtp connections so you can't send email using Gmail. For me I use mailjet.

Answer (score 0):

A user cannot send you an email via django unless he has enabled API access in his gmail settings.

A possible solution is to self-send you an email (via EMAIL_HOST_USER) containing the specifications entered by the user who contacts you (email, text of the message and more)